# How do i structure templates so they're polymorphic?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have two types of class:

```
Repository<A> a;
Repository<B> b;
```

And i'd like to create an interface, which can return either types of these classes, such as:

```
class RepositoryInterface {
   virtual Repository<*> getRepository() = 0;
}
```

Which i'd then like two classes to implement. For example:

```
class RepositoryA : RepositoryInterface {
  public:
  virtual Repository<A> getRepository();
}

class RepositoryB : RepositoryInterface {
  public:
  virtual Repository<B> getRepository();
}
```

The repositories would then be used as following:

```
class example {

   run(int x){
    auto repository = repositoryLookup(x);

    repository.deleteAll();
   }

   Repository<*> repositoryLookup(int x) {
     if ( x == 1 ) {
       return Repository<A>();  
     } else {
       return Repository<B>();
     }
   }

}
```

The reason i want to do this is to enable a modular repository system, where anyone can plugin a repository without having to amend the `run` function. I've tried using `boost::any` without success, as unless i'm mistaken, i'm still required to cast the repository to the type i need.

Any guidance on an approach to make this repository system abstract would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Virtual functions and templates don't really mix.  Templates are a compile time construct and virtual is run time.  What you can do though is use a `std::variant`/`std::any`.

Comment: Derive the template class from a non-templated polymorphic base.   Have your functions return a pointer or reference to the base.    (That does, naturally, mean the object returned - by pointer or reference - exists at least until it is used).

Comment: The question i'm asking is "How to structure template classes so they're polymorphic?"

Comment: The same way you would "structure" any two random classes, whatever "structure" means. This has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: `Repository<A> a()` is a function declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though their names are alike, `Repository<A>` and `Repository<B>` are completely different types. You'll need to make them share a common type, something like:

```
class RepositoryBase { /*virtuals etc*/ };

template <typename T>
class Repository : public RepositoryBase 
{};
```

Comment: Yes you're right, it's just struck me now that they're infact completely separate types. Thank you very much for the insight.